# After eject Expo project unable to run app

Tags: react-native, expo, create-react-app

After ejecting expo project when i run app getting error

```
Failed to resolve: host.exp.exponent:expoview:29.0.0
```

in my gradle file i am using

`implementation('host.exp.exponent:expoview:29.0.0')`

any suggestion is really appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to install the `expokit` module?

```
npm install --save expokit
```